# Filtering objects with each object's foreignkey property and object's many to many property

Tags: django

I have a basic chat model:

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Membership', through_fields=('thread', 'user'))

class Membership(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

class Message(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

I am trying to filter an object by its foreignkey field's property, with the object's many to many fields data, then order by the foreignkey's field.

Meaning, I would like to get only those threads whose message timestamp is greater than user's membership date joined for the thread, and order whose message was sent last.

Example:

```
Thread.objects.filter(members=user, message__timestamp__gte= < thread's user's membership date joined >).distinct()
```

I can create a for loop and go through each of the threads and then return a new list, but is there any way that I could do it while filtering itself or maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
thread_id_list = Message.objects.filter(timestamp__gte=< thread's user's membership date joined >).values_list('thread__id', flat=True)
threads = Thread.objects.filter(id__in = therad_id_list)
```